# Python help sorting after hyphen

Tags: python

I am getting data from a json request. I use these lines here to iterate over my json object and remove duplicates and then sort it by the first character:

```
 for x in resources:  
 roads.append( os.linesep + x["description"])   
 TrafficHome = list(set(roads))  
 TrafficHome.sort()
```

After I run those I have an output like this:

```
[u'\r\nAt I-55 - Construction work.', u'\r\nAt Willow Ave - Accident.', u'\r\nAt Wolf Rd/Exit 16 - Accident.', u'\r\nBetween 55th St and Plainfield Rd - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween County Farm Rd and Windermere Dr - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween Geneva Rd and St Charles Rd - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween Jeans Rd and Knoll Wood Rd - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween Knoll Wood Rd and Jeans Rd - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween Lavergne Ave and Roy Ave - Construction work.', u'\r\nBetween Roy Ave and Lavergne Ave - Construction work.', u'\r\nBetween St Charles Rd and Geneva Rd - Roadwork.', u'\r\nBetween Windermere Dr and County Farm Rd - Roadwork.']
```

I then run this line:

```
TrafficHome = ' '.join(map(str, TrafficHome))
```

I then have a string like so:

> At I-55 - Construction work.
>   At Willow Ave - Accident.
>   At Wolf Rd/Exit 16 - Accident.
>   Between 55th St and Plainfield Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between County Farm Rd and Windermere Dr - Roadwork.
>   Between Geneva Rd and St Charles Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Jeans Rd and Knoll Wood Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Knoll Wood Rd and Jeans Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Lavergne Ave and Roy Ave - Construction work.
>   Between Roy Ave and Lavergne Ave - Construction work.
>   Between St Charles Rd and Geneva Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Windermere Dr and County Farm Rd - Roadwork.

I would like to sort it alphabetically after the hyphen like this:

> At Willow Ave - Accident.
>   At Wolf Rd/Exit 16 - Accident.
>   At I-55 - Construction work.
>   Between Lavergne Ave and Roy Ave - Construction work.
>   Between Roy Ave and Lavergne Ave - Construction work.
>   Between 55th St and Plainfield Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between County Farm Rd and Windermere Dr - Roadwork.
>   Between Geneva Rd and St Charles Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Jeans Rd and Knoll Wood Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Knoll Wood Rd and Jeans Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between St Charles Rd and Geneva Rd - Roadwork.
>   Between Windermere Dr and County Farm Rd - Roadwork.

In some cases there could be 2 hypens like:

> At I-55 - Construction work.

So I would need to account for that, I am not sure the best way to accomplish this. I don't know if I should try to manipulate the string or before I convert it to a string. I am very new to python and I am using this for a Tasker task because Javascript was not working for me.

Any help, guidance, or input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda function as your key in `sorted()` should solve the problem.

```
sortedlist = sorted(list, lambda x: x.rsplit('-', 1)[-1])
```

On python 2.x you might have to do this:

```
sortedlist = sorted(list, key=lambda x: x.rsplit('-', 1)[-1])
```

`rsplit('-', 1)` splits your list into 2 pieces, splitting from the last instance of `-`. This should work as long as your statuses at the end of the string do not contain hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(x,key=lambda s: s[s.rfind('-'):])
```

the argument `key` is a function which gives `sorted` the value on which to compare your data for sorting.  I am proposing `rfind` to find the last `-`, this unfortunately assumes you will not have hyphens in the second half of your data.  Using that index the data returned is the substr from that point to the end of your string.